# how to if condition row hide when condition is false RDLC

Tags: rdlc, ssrs-tablix

How to hide row if condition is fale  please check below image and please help me this

```
=IIf(Fields!OrderTypeId.Value = "1", Fields!Orders.Value,0)
=IIf(Fields!OrderTypeId.Value = "2", Fields!Orders.Value,0)
=IIf(Fields!OrderTypeId.Value = "3", Fields!Orders.Value,0)
```

[I want Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LRQT.jpg)

[But when condition is false its show 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZUZZ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful:

```
=((Fields!OrderTypeId.Value = "3" Or Fields!OrderTypeId.Value = "2" Or 
   Fields!OrderTypeId.Value = "1") 
 And (Fields!Orders.Value = 0))
```

Thanks